# Count specific value in a cell from source and split the cells of target file according to that count value using macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have two Excel files (source A & source B) as source and one target file. I want to compare the data of two source files and then paste that data to target file. But for one record in source A there have many values in Source B, so I need to find a solution for split cells in target file.

First I have to find count of specific values in a cell and then split cells can be done according to that count value.

[image]

Source  A

```
SNumber
1000245
1000567
1000789
```

Source B

```
INumber      IStore
1000245       111
1000245       234
1000245       333
1000567       412
1000567       502
```

Target:

```
INumber IStore

1000245 111
    234
    333
1000567 412
    502
```

Comment: i don't see the difference between source2 and target, other than the format. Could you please clarify your question regarding the role of source1?

Comment: Can you add an auxiliary column in any of the source worksheets?

Comment: yes only format will be changed... means for 1000245 there are 3 values so I just need to split the cells for 1000245

Comment: first I am comparing data between source A and  source B . when I will find the match then I need to paste that data(Inumber,IStore) from source B to target. you can see for 1000245 there are 3 values(111,234,333) so I need count of same values(1000245) then only I can split the cells for  111,234,333

Comment: You can take a look at the URL @Jeeped already posted. You can do the same without VBA, just using PivotTable. First you need an aux. column in Source B where you make a normal VLOOKUP between INumber and SNumber. For easiness, the result should be 1,0 - True,False... Therefore, the VLOOKUP should have an IF Statement before. Then make a normal PivotTable of Source B, filter by the new aux. column and [change the layout to tabular form](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/change-the-layout-and-format-of-a-pivottable-report-4ea54f15-81dc-4e42-be49-00eadbbbd1e5#__toc273370200)